# UIImagePickerController asks for access to photos

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

Even though I am not saving the photos anywhere but whenever I access the edited image in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` function, iOS asks me for permission to access photos on the device.

Any idea how to prevent it from asking permission.

**Adding UIImagePickerController**

```
- (IBAction)addPhotoButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    picker.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

**didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image;

   image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];


    if (image == nil)
        image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05f);
    _locationImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:imageData];

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any way shy of writing your own editing control (which isn't that hard though) Then you have full control.

the UIImagePicker is asking that - I guess - because it saves the original image temporarily as if it were saved indeed...

Comment: can you please elaborate on how I am accessing photos, since I'm not directly accessing or saving anything to the user album? Is there a documentation link I can refer to.

Comment: I tried... search for a different editing control if you like

Answer (score 0):

you must know that when accessing the photo gallery for the first time the **permission must be requested** from the user.

http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/14/apple-requires-user-permission-before-apps-can-access-personal-data-in-ios-6/

Alo you must check the permission by

```
AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType];
if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
  // do your logic
} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){
  // denied
} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
  // restricted, normally won't happen
} else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
  // not determined?!
  [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:mediaType completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
    if(granted){
      NSLog(@"Granted access to %@", mediaType);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Not granted access to %@", mediaType);
    }
  }];
} else {
  // impossible, unknown authorization status
}
```

Comment: sorry, I was debugging it. The problem persists when I do it.  I need it to be editable but not to show me the photo permission access.